# loading data efficiently in tensorflow from pickle files

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle

I have about 10000 pickle files that I should read and feed to a tensorflow model to train it. I do this process in a loop by loading a file at the time and do some preprocessing and then train using this file and repeat. Is there a more efficient way to do this.
The code looks something like that for this part:

```
for filename in os.listdir("training_data"):
    x = load_data(filename)
    #some preprocessing
    feed_dict = construct_feed_dictionary(x)
    out = sess.run([model.opt_op, model.loss, model.accuracy],feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: There is probably no faster way to read the pickle files. However it might make more sense to store your data in a different format if you are looking for performance improvements.

Comment: What about pipeling ? I read about it somewhere, is it suitable for this situation ?

Comment: You might be able to convert your data from pickle to another format and use `tf.data.Dataset` [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) but that might require an overhaul of your existing pipeline